# UseSwaggerUI :: UseRequestInterceptor => adding api version on request

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, c#-5.0, request-headers

trying to setup API versioning by Header.
All other stuff is ok, resolved the existing conflict that everyone knows about having api versions with same endpoint.

however there is an issue with it as it will only use default api version for request;
after exploring some some other options, it may seems that best way would be handling "UseRequestInterceptor";

My issue is that I actually am clueless on how to declare function to be be used here; tried to declare function on injected javascript file, but it seems not be right way.

can someone around give me a clue?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the one's that may be trying to get something as I wished for.

Actually there is 2 answers:

- swagger versioning with version on header request
- swagger UseRequestInterceptor howTo\syntax.

for the one's trying to add api versioning with swagger and having same endpoint for each version, you will have an error about not being possible to have same endpoint for 2 methods. Documentation says that for rest services you should not do that - for me it is not a right answer as although I may be pursuing a different expected result or a different performance, I do not want to break consumer.

so first workaround:

```
            services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.ResolveConflictingActions(o => o.FirstOrDefault());
                
                options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "api.swagger.Versioning", Version = "v1" });
                options.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "api.swagger.Versioning", Version = "v2" });
            });
```

notice resolve conflicts row;
this row picks first version and that will be okay - or not;

for any request it will not throw header for version api. which will end by any request you do will target default version. nice!

After testing some options and reading around, got the idea of using **UseRequestInterceptor**, but missed the syntax on how to.

for my code I opted on having header for version as "api";

so in the end you will have something like:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCustomMiddleware();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            { 

                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(swaggerUiOptions =>
                {
                    swaggerUiOptions.HeadContent = "Swagger API demo";


                    var fn =  "(request) => { var swaggerSelect = document.querySelector('#swagger-ui .swagger-container .topbar select'); if(swaggerSelect) { var selected = swaggerSelect.selectedOptions; if( selected ) { var version = selected[0].text.split('|')[1]; request.headers['api']=version; }  }; return request; }";


                
          
                    swaggerUiOptions.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "api.swagger.Versioning v1|1.0");
                    swaggerUiOptions.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "api.swagger.Versioning v2|2.0");

                    swaggerUiOptions.InjectJavascript("/js/inject.js");
                    swaggerUiOptions.UseRequestInterceptor(fn);
                });
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

basically I went for looking if it was possible to parse the value of the version -  when it became possible I added it on header.

There may be some more elegant ways of doing this, and hopefully someone will come here telling me that - but it was what I came out on my own.

My code sample:
https://github.com/figueiredorj/api.swagger

side note about Swashbuckle.AspNetCore -it seems it works from 6.0.7